# Paginating Django query results in a table

Tags: django, django-views, pagination

I am having issues with paginating my query results. When I use the query without pagination it works as intended, but once I add the pagination to the query I am seeing results on the last page that do not match what was defined in the search.

For example, if I search a date like april 5th, 2023 I get 53 as my last page, after clicking on 53 to view the page 54 appears in the pagination as the last page. If you navigate to 54 it has items from later dates. Also I noticed if you navigate to a page in the query then try to navigate back to the first page the table then shows results from earlier dates.

I have tried researching and fixing this but I am at a loss, any help would be greatly appreciated.

models.py:

```
class Package(models.Model):
    barcode = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    barcode_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True)
    origin = models.CharField('Origin Location', max_length=50, choices=[(location.locations, location.locations) for location in Location.objects.all()])
    destination = models.CharField('Destination Location', max_length=50, choices=[(location.locations, location.locations) for location in Location.objects.all()])
    description = models.CharField('Description', max_length=50)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('Date Created', default=timezone.now)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default=320557)
    status = models.CharField('Status', default='Created', max_length=50)
```

views.py:

```
def search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    return render(request, 'search/search.html', {'form': form, 'navbar': 'search'})

def search_results(request):    
    # Get the search query parameters from the GET request
    description = request.GET.get('description', '').strip()
    date = request.GET.get('date', '').strip()
    barcode = request.GET.get('barcode', '').strip()
    employee_name = request.GET.get('employee_name', '').strip()
    employee_number = request.GET.get('employee_number', '').strip()
    
    # Build the filter conditions using Q objects
    filters = Q()
    if description:
        filters &= Q(description__icontains=description)
    if date:
        filters &= Q(date_created__icontains=date)
    if barcode:
        filters &= Q(barcode__icontains=barcode)
    if employee_name:
        filters &= Q(employee__name__icontains=employee_name)
    if employee_number:
        filters &= Q(employee__employee_number__icontains=employee_number)
        
    # Perform the search using the filters
    package_search = Package.objects.filter(filters).distinct()     
    
    # pagination logic
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(package_search, 12)
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page)
    try:
        package = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        package = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        package = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)   
        
    # set page_range to limit the number of page links displayed
    max_pages = 20
    num_pages = paginator.num_pages
    middle_page = int(max_pages/2)
    if num_pages <= max_pages:
        page_range = range(1, num_pages+1)
    elif package.number <= middle_page:
        page_range = range(1, max_pages+1)
    elif package.number >= num_pages - middle_page:
        page_range = range(num_pages-max_pages+1, num_pages+1)
    else:
        page_range = range(package.number-middle_page, package.number+middle_page+1)
    
    last_page = paginator.num_pages - 10
    
    context = {
        'package_search': page_obj,
        'navbar': 'search',
        'page_range': page_range,
        'last_page': last_page,
        
    }
    # Render the search results template with the package_search queryset
    return render(request, 'search/search_results.html', context)
```

search_results.html:

```
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <nav aria-label="Page Navigation">        
            {% if package_search.has_other_pages %}
              <ul class="pagination">
                {% if package_search.has_previous %}
                  <li class= "page-item"><a class="page-link" href='?{% if filters %}q={{Q}}&{% endif %}page={{ package_search.previous_page_number }}'>&laquo;</a></li>
                  {% if package_search.previous_page_number >= 11 %}
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?{% if filters %}q={{Q}}&{% endif %}page=1">1</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="">...</a></li>
                  {% else %}
                  <li class="page-item hidden">
                    <a href=""></a>
                    <a href="?{% if filters %}q={{Q}}&{% endif %}page=1"></a>
                  {% endif %}
                {% else %}
                </li>
                  <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <span class="page-link">&laquo;</span>
                  </li>
                {% endif %}
                {% for i in page_range %}
                  {% if package_search.number == i %}
                  <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page">
                    <span class="page-link " href="?{% if filters %}q={{Q}}&{% endif %}page={{ i }}">{{i}}<span class="sr-only"></span></span>
                  </li>
                  {% else %}
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link bs-success-text" href="?{% if filters %}q={{Q}}&{% endif %}page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                  {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% if package_search.has_next %}
                  {% if package_search.next_page_number <= last_page %}
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="">...</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?{% if filters %}q={{Q}}&{% endif %}page={{ package_search.paginator.num_pages }}">{{package_search.paginator.num_pages}}</a></li>
                  {% else %}
                    <li class="page-item hidden">
                      <a href=""></a>
                      <a href="?{% if filters %}q={{Q}}&{% endif %}page={{ package_search.paginator.num_pages }}"></a>
                    </li>
                  {% endif %}
                  <li class= "page-item"><a class="page-link" href='?{% if filters %}q={{Q}}&{% endif %}page={{ package_search.next_page_number }}'>&raquo;</a></li>
                {% else %}
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                  <span class="page-link">&raquo;</span>
                </li>
                {% endif %}
              </ul>
            {% endif %}
          </nav>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Page method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/paginator/#page-class) differently to avoid error. And also use [Paginator.ELLIPSIS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/paginator/#django.core.paginator.Paginator.ELLIPSIS) with a template tag.

Here's an example.

#### views.py

```
def search_results(request):    
    # Get the search query parameters from the GET request
    description = request.GET.get('description', '').strip()
    date = request.GET.get('date', '').strip()
    barcode = request.GET.get('barcode', '').strip()
    employee_name = request.GET.get('employee_name', '').strip()
    employee_number = request.GET.get('employee_number', '').strip()

    # Get query params
    query_params = request.GET.copy()

    page_number = 1
    # If page is define in request paramater, we get and remove it from params
    if 'page' in query_params:
        page_number = query_params.pop('page', 1)[0]

    # Build the filter conditions using Q objects
    filters = Q()
    if description:
        filters &= Q(description__icontains=description)
    if date:
        filters &= Q(date_created__icontains=date)
    if barcode:
        filters &= Q(barcode__icontains=barcode)
    if employee_name:
        filters &= Q(employee__name__icontains=employee_name)
    if employee_number:
        filters &= Q(employee__employee_number__icontains=employee_number)
    
    # Perform the search using the filters
    package_search = Package.objects.filter(filters).distinct()     

    # pagination logic
    paginator = Paginator(package_search, 12) # Max elements per page
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number) # New get page number

    context = {
        'package_search': package_search,
        'page_obj': page_obj,
        'paginator': paginator,
        'filters': query_params,
        'navbar': 'search',
    }

    # Render the search results template with the package_search queryset
    return render(request, 'search/search_results.html', context)
```

#### my_custom_tag.py

Create the simple_tag in my_app/templatetags/my_custom_tag.py.
This tag will return a list of page number with some removed using the method [Paginator.get_elided_page_range(number, *, on_each_side=3, on_ends=2)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/paginator/#django.core.paginator.Paginator.get_elided_page_range)

```
# my_custom_tag.py
from django import template
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_proper_elided_page_range(paginator, number, on_each_side=3, on_ends=2):
    """
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/paginator/#django.core.paginator.Paginator.get_elided_page_range
    """
    paginator = Paginator(paginator.object_list, paginator.per_page)
    return paginator.get_elided_page_range(number=number,
                                           on_each_side=on_each_side,
                                           on_ends=on_ends)
```

#### search_results.html

```
{% load my_custom_tag %}

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <nav aria-label="Page Navigation">        
    {% if package_search %}
      <ul class="pagination">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
          <li class= "page-item"><a class="page-link" href='?page=1{% if filters %}&{{ query_params.urlencode }}{% endif %}'>&laquo;&laquo;</a></li>
          <li class= "page-item"><a class="page-link" href='?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}{% if filters %}&{{ query_params.urlencode }}{% endif %}'>&laquo;</a></li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="page-item disabled">
            <span class="page-link">&laquo;&laquo;</span>
          </li>
          <li class="page-item disabled">
            <span class="page-link">&laquo;</span>
          </li>
        {% endif %} 
        {% get_proper_elided_page_range paginator page_obj.number 1 1 as page_range %}
        {% for page_num in page_range %}
          {% if page_obj.number == page_num %}
            <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page">
              <span class="page-link " href="#">{{ page_num }}<span class="sr-only"></span></span>
            </li>
          {% else %}
            {% if page_num == paginator.ELLIPSIS %}
              <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="">{{ paginator.ELLIPSIS }}</a></li>
            {% else %}
              <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link bs-success-text" href="?page={{ page_num }}{% if filters %}&{{ query_params.urlencode }}{% endif %}">{{ page_num }}</a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}{% if filters %}&{{ query_params.urlencode }}{% endif %}">&raquo;</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}{% if filters %}&{{ query_params.urlencode }}{% endif %}">&raquo;&raquo;</a></li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="page-item disabled">
            <span class="page-link">&raquo;</span>
          </li>
          <li class="page-item disabled">
            <span class="page-link">&raquo;&raquo;</span>
          </li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
  </nav>
</div>
```

I've written the code from your example but you can modify it as needed.

Please tell me if that help you correct your issue.

**EDIT:**  "search_results.html" was corrected

Comment: I tried this, I like the idea of using page method instead but I am getting errors stating that the page number is less than 1 I tried toying with it to correct the error but was unable to resolve it.

Comment: @Austin My bad, there was an error in "search_results.html" in the "for" part. I've corrected my post. You can now use the "search_results.html" to update your code