# How can I change numbers in a url parameter in Django Template?

Tags: django

I'm trying to make a pagination system.
I want to change a number in a url parameter.
The URL is like this;

https://example.com?page=1

What I'm trying in a template is below, but it doesn't work.

```
<a class="next_page" rel="next" href="{{request.build_absolute_uri|cut:'&page={{current_page}}'}}page={{current_page|add:1}}">Next</a>
```

I'm passing current_page variable from view.py and remove the old page number from the url parameter and then giving the new number.
The problem is I can't use current_page variable in the cut filter.
How should I resolve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to use [Django Paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/paginator/) ? Here's an [answer with an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76113773/12545861)

Comment: You can easily complete all the computations in the view. And pass all the _prior, next, first, last, total, current_ to the template as ready to use data.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply pass the next page to a template:

```
<a class="next_page" rel="next" href="{{request.build_absolute_uri}}?page={{next_page}}">Next</a>
```